# The modal message does not show the correct data when I added bootstrap into my django project

Tags: python, django, database, web

```
**homepage.html**

{% for country in countries %} 
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">{{ country.id }}</th>
          <td>{{ country.name }}</td>
          <td align="center"><a class="btn btn-warning" href="{% url 'edit_country' country.id %}">Edit</a></td>
          <td align="center"><a class="btn btn-danger" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">Delete</a></td>
          <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Delete post</h5>
                  <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                  Are you sure you want to delete {{ country.name }}?
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" href="{% url 'delete_country' country.id %}">Delete</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </tr>
        
        
        {% endfor %}
```

**views.py**

```
def homepage(request):
    countries = Countries.objects.all()
    context = {'countries':countries}
    return render(request,'homepage.html',context)
```

**models.py**

```
class Countries(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=75)
    landmark = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
    food = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
    entertainment = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='travel', default='default.png',null=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Here I have a problem that when I use the Django component Modal although I used for loop to pass the parameter `country` the modal message could appear but it does not show the correct `{{country.name}}` data. I tried clicking the delete button on the second row but the message still only shows the data of the first object instead of the second one. May I ask is there a problem that I put the modal block incorrectly or should I use JavaScript in order to have the modal message showing the correct data?

[Modal message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BaCE5.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wrong modal shows because all the modal elements are using the same `id`, so when you click any modal it always shows the first modal that is `#exampleModal`.

So what you can do is update the `id` of the modal to include the `country.id` and also the target where the `id` is referenced. This will make each modal unique in the HTML and will allow the right toggle to show up when the table row is clicked.

For Example

```html
<tr>
...
<td align="center"><a class="btn btn-danger" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal-{{country.id}}">Delete</a></td>
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal-{{country.id}}" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
...
</div>
```